# Radicale with uwsgi and Apache with Debian: Connection refused

Tags: apache, uwsgi, caldav, carddav, radicale

I want to set up Radicale for CardDav and CalDav syncing.

I set up Apache and want to access Radicale with uwsgi. When I enter the user name it says 'Service Unavailable'.

The error logfile shows:
[proxy:error] [pid 21029:tid 140292405581568] (111)Connection refused: AH02454: uwsgi: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/uwsgi/app/radicale/socket (radicale) failed
[:error] [pid 21029:tid 140292405581568] [client 178.251.71.190:33788] AH10101: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS:0

I am running Debian buster. Https traffic seems to work, I get asked for username/password.

I took examples/apache2-vhost.conf and just edited the domain/host name and corrected the conf-available file to radicale-uwsgi.conf (bug) and put it into /etc/apache2/sites-available (+ a2ensite ...).

I also edited /etc/radicale/config but for me it looks like that it's not coming that far.

I have never worked with unix sockets and uwsgi so far, so I am a bit lost now. Can anyone give me some hints?

Thank you,
Flo.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question but like an admin one, maybe superuser is the right forum for this?

Comment: Thank you for this hint that superuser would be a better forum. I may use it next time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems finally:

First: libapache2-mod-proxy-uwsgi is a suggested package, however, for running Radicale in the in Debian suggested way it is necessary.

At the beginning I haven't realized that this was missing as I could enable proxy-uwsgi (link in sites-enabled did exist). I found it through desperately trying anything.

Second: I changed the filesystem_folder in /etc/radicale/config. But the default value (/var/lib/radicale/collections) is also anchored in /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/radicale.ini and as home directory of user radicale. Propably this all needs to changed to have it working. I changed filesystem_folder in /etc/radicale/config back to the default value for now and after that it finally worked.

I will file a bug report for this package.